# Javascript DOM error - Object type not supported

Tags: jquery, sorting, tabs

My problem is with a jQuery Sort Table and a jQuery Tab interface in my application. With Chrome and Firefox, I have no problem. But with IE 6/7 this error pops up:

> Object doesn't support this property
>   or method.

The code:

```
 $(function(){    
    $("#sortable").tablesorter();
    $("#dashboardtabs").tabs({ fxSlide: true, fxFade: true, fxSpeed: 'normal' });
 });
```

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Try disabling each function to find out which one is causing the trouble. I've had trouble with tablesorter in the past so I'm guessing it might be the one giving the error. But knowing which one gives the error would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I had 2 jquery libraries. This caused some sort of a confusion. Solved it. Thanks anyway, Fudgey.